If $x+y=3\sqrt{xy}$, $\frac xy=\frac{a+\sqrt b}{a-\sqrt b}$, given $x,y>0$ and $a,b$ are coprime, then $a+b=?$

If the sum of two numbers $x,y$ is $3$ times their geometric mean and $\frac xy=\frac{a+\sqrt b}{a-\sqrt b}$, given $x,y>0$ and $a,b$ are coprime, then find $a+b$

My Attempt:
$x+y=3\sqrt{xy}\implies \sqrt{\frac xy}+\sqrt{\frac yx}=3$
Solving the quadratic, I get $\sqrt{\frac xy}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt 5}2\implies\frac xy=\frac{7\pm3\sqrt 5}2$

Do you know about the divdendo-componendo rule?

@MathGuy yes...

Picking up from $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y} = \frac{7 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{2}$, substitute back into $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y} = \frac{a + \sqrt{b}}{a - \sqrt{b}}$ to get
$$
-5a + 9\sqrt{b} = \pm 3a\sqrt{5} \mp 3\sqrt{5b}.
$$
The right-hand side only has a rational component if $b$ is of the form $5k^2$. Can you finish it from here?

Yes, I think $a=3, b=5$

Agreed, equating rational parts gives $a = 3k^2$. Then $k = 1$ due to $a$ and $b$ being coprime

Using dividendo and componendo gives:
$$\frac{x + y}{y} = \frac{3 \sqrt{xy}}{y} = 3 \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} = \frac{2a}{a - \sqrt{b}}$$
Now using what you obtained:
$$\frac{2a}{3 \left(a - \sqrt{b} \right)} = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{2}{3 \mp \sqrt{5}}$$
$$\implies 3a - 3 \sqrt{b} = 3a \mp a\sqrt{5}$$
which yields $b = 5, a = 3$ or $b = 5, a=-3$.
Hence the possible values of $a + b$ are $2, 8$.

Thankyou, means a lot.

You have approached the question correctly. Now, using the dividendo and componendo rule,
$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{7 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$\implies\frac{a+\sqrt b}{a-\sqrt b}=\frac{7 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$\implies\frac{a}{\sqrt b}=\frac{9 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{5 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}$$
$$\implies\frac{a}{\sqrt b}=\frac3{\sqrt5}\times\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt5 \pm 3}$$
Taking the plus sign, we get:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt b}=\frac3{\sqrt5}$$
$$\implies a=3, b=5$$
Taking the minus sign, we get:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt b}=\frac{-3}{\sqrt5}$$
$$\implies a=-3, b=5$$
$$\therefore\boxed{a+b=8, 2}$$
